# Convert the string to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm taking a date as an input to textbox and compare that input date with current date for validation. but i don't know how to convert string date to date.

`var dateText = document.getElementById("textBoxId").value;`

Simply I want to compare `dateText` with `Date()`

Comment: Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: You can use `Date.parse()`. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse.

Comment: The basics of this are not hard to research and you are expected to do some searching before asking questions here. Question shows no research effort whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the format you are allowing a user to input into the Textbook#textBoxId, if you are ensuring a valid format, for example MM/DD/YYYY then you can use Javascript `Date` to parse the string into a JS Date instance:

```
var d = Date.parse(dateString);
```

Another example:

```
var d = Date.parse("March 21, 2012");
```

You can also use Date.parse implicitly like so:

```
var d = new Date("March 21, 2012");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try Date.parse()

For example:

```
// getting a timestamp
console.log(Date.parse('2016/01/01')) // output 1451635200000

// converting to a date object
var dateObj = Date(Date.parse('2016/01/01'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `new Date()` to get Date object passing valid date string.
>
> `Dateobj.getTime()` => *The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date*
>
> `Dateobj.setHours()` => *method sets the hour of a date object. This method can also be used to set the minutes, seconds and milliseconds.*

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var dateText = document.getElementById("textBoxId").value;
  var inputDate = new Date(dateText);
  inputDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //to exclude hours,minutes,sec and milliseconds
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //to exclude hours,minutes,sec and milliseconds
  if (inputDate.getTime() == today.getTime()) {
    alert('Date selected is today!');
  } else if (inputDate.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
    alert('Date selected is greater!');
  } else {
    alert('Date selected is smaller!')
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="textBoxId">
<button id='check'>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date.parse()` method but it works only with `MM/DD/YYYY` format,
where

`MM = month`
`DD = day`
`YYYY = year`

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncwyr987/1/)

Comment: Yes, you can, but expect it to fail as parsing of date strings is almost entirely implementation dependent.

Comment: Oh, and *Date.parse* works with may formats other than m/d/y, but the results are very inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I too recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) however it is a big download. There are some odd things with JavaScript dates but let's go for it anyway:

HTML:

```
<p>
  Date <input id="date" type=="text" />
</p>
<p>
  Output: <span id="output"></span>
</p>

<p>
  Enter a date as MM/DD/YYYY and then click out of the input to trigger the change event.
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  var text = evt.target.value;
  var parts = text.split('/');
  if (parts.length !== 3) {
    alert('Invalid date format!');
    output.innerText = '';
  } else {
    var asDate = new Date(parts[2], parts[0], parts[1]);
    output.innerText = asDate.toString();
  }
});
```

I demonstrate a low level way to parse the date -- expect it to be in format MM/DD/YYYY and then use string functions to split by '/' into the 3 parts. Feed those into `new Date(YYYY, MM, DD)`. We are lazy here and don't convert the parts from string to integer but it still works. A more robust solution would be to convert the parts and validate them.

However, it is much easier to use a library for this because of leap years and other date oddities.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5n79j48n/

Reference: [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: The way you've parsed the string is fine, it will not have any issue with leap years. To validate the input, just check that `asDate.getMonth() == parts[0]-1`. That's it.

Comment: @RobG yes, I was thinking more about validating the date within the month. Most of the problems are easy to work around but there are a fair number of subtle issues.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function getmonth(txtmonth){
 var txtmonth = txtmonth.toLowerCase();
 arr=["","january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"];
 arrMonth=["","jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","oct","nov","dec"];
 strMonth = arr.indexOf(txtmonth);
 if (strMonth==-1){
  //check again month to match with arrMonth
  strMonth = arrMonth.indexOf(txtmonth);
 }
 return strMonth;
}
function getClientDate(){
 var client_date = document.getElementById("txtDate").value;
 var client_date = client_date.replace(/\s+/g, "");
 var date = client_date.split("/");
   
 var day = date[0];
 //Check Day
 if (day > 31 || day.length>2){
  alert("Invalid Date. Please Enter Valid Date.");
  document.getElementById("txtDate").value="";
  document.getElementById("txtDate").focus();
  return;
 }
 var month = date[1];
 
 strMonth = getmonth(month);
 
 if (strMonth==-1){
  var strMonth = date[1];
  //check Month
    if (strMonth>12){
     alert("Enter Valid Month");
     document.getElementById("txtDate").value="";
     document.getElementById("txtDate").focus();
     return;
    }
 }
 
 var year = date[2];
 //check Year;
 if (year.length>4){
  alert("Enter Valid Year");
  document.getElementById("txtDate").value="";
  document.getElementById("txtDate").focus();
  return;
 }
 //MS SQL FORMAT DATE
 var client_date = year + "-" + strMonth + "-" + day;
 document.getElementById("CDate").innerHTML=client_date;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Date of Birth: Eg;</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtDate" onchange="getClientDate(this.value)" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
  <span id="CDate"></span>
</form>
```